# Android: How to only allow 1 radio button to be selected when there are 3 radio groups?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have 3 radio groups, a total of 9 radio buttons. I separate them in groups because I would want to have them nicely aligned in the layout. However, I would like to limit users to be able to only select 1 radio buttons out of these 9, as a complete beginner I would like to know how. Thank you very much.

Comment: do that programmatically

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity's Java file, get all the radio buttons by calling `(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button)`, and set a listener on each one that will de-select all the other radio buttons. Ideally, you could iterate over a list of these radio buttons rather than writing 9 separate anonymous inner classes.